RegEx: final word duplication
I want to trim a string to include 20 words at most using RegEx.
Here's the text I'm trimming:
const text = `Space travel is the ultimate adventure! Imagine soaring past the stars
and exploring new worlds. It's the stuff of dreams and science fiction,
but believe it or not, space travel is a real thing. Humans and robots
are constantly venturing out into the cosmos to uncover its secrets and
push the boundaries of what's possible`;

Here's the RegEx pattern:
const regex = new RegExp(`^(\\S+\\s+){1,20}`);

When I do text.match(regex) I'm expecting to get this:
Space travel is the ultimate adventure! Imagine soaring past the stars
and exploring new worlds. It's the stuff of dreams
...But what I'm getting instead is this:
Space travel is the ultimate adventure! Imagine soaring past the stars
and exploring new worlds. It's the stuff of dreams dreams
I noticed that when I do regex.exec(text) I'm getting an array with 2 elements: the expected text and that "dreams".
Setting g flag resolves the issue and removes the "dreams" from the end of the line, but what I don't understand is why it even appears?
Another curious observation: setting (\\S+\\s+) as non-capturing also resolves the problem:
const regex = new RegExp(`^(?:\\S+\\s+){1,20}`);

Does anyone know why this is happening?
Thanks!

Don't use new RegExp for constant regular expressions. It's only needed when creating the regexp dynamically.

You should log the return value from match, which will reveal that it’s the same array returned by exec (and not a single string with “dreams” repeated). Being included in this array is exactly the distinction between a capturing and non-capturing group. By the way, JavaScript has regex literals: const regex = /^(?:\S+\s*){1,20}/;

Element N of the array is capture group #N from the regexp.
